# prometheus relabel_config drop action not working

Tags: prometheus

I've been trying to drop unused metrics (before scrape) to lighten the load on a Prometheus cluster via `relabel_configs`:

```
- job_name: nginx-ingress-controller-metrics
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: endpoints
    namespaces:
      names:
      - <some-namespace>
  relabel_configs:
  # single
  - source_labels: [__name__]
    regex: nginx_ingress_controller_response_size_bucket
    action: drop
  # multiple
  - source_labels: [__name__]
    regex: nginx_ingress_controller_(request_size_bucket|response_duration_seconds_bucket|bytes_sent_bucket|bytes_sent_sum)
    action: drop
```

However, I am not seeing any of these metrics dropped (before scrape) and they are scraped and ingested as I can query them via `PromQL`.

I've tried many variations of the same config (i.e. quotes, parentheses, etc.). Any idea why these targets are still scraped/ingested?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you declare in `relabel_configs` happens before Prometheus even makes a connection to an exporter. No connection means there is no metrics and no labels yet, so you can't drop metrics by `__name__` at this point.

What you actually need to use is `metric_relabel_configs`. This relabeling step happens after Prometheus has retrieved data from an exporter, but ***before*** data is actually saved into the database. Here's an example:

```yaml
metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__name__]
    regex: my_useless_metric.*
    action: drop
```

If you're curious "what's the point of relabel_configs then?", `relabel_configs` operate metrics on the scale of hosts. Using service discovery information (which is available at this point) you can use relabeling to change address, port or to make a decision whether this instance should be scraped at all.

Comment: Interesting. That makes sense. Thanks. So how can I drop a metric before scrape? I don't even want to scrape unused metrics to ease the load. I am aware of `metric_relabel_configs` but I believe this is after scrape, before ingest.

Comment: I am also looking at a deck from a presenter at promcon (Munich, 2018) drop a metric by label `__address__` using `relabel_configs`. See slide 34 (https://promcon.io/2018-munich/slides/taking-advantage-of-relabeling.pdf).

Comment: @danksim There's no way to do that. You have to retrieve (=scrape) metrics before you know their names. Scrape in this context means that Prometheus does an HTTP GET request and fetch all labels present into memory. They you can drop some before they get into the database (=before ingesting). This is not possible to achieve with `__address__`, because it is simply `host:port` of the target instance. You could only drop all metrics from an instance by messing with it.

Comment: While that makes sense, I am confused as to the wording here (https://www.robustperception.io/relabelling-can-discard-targets-timeseries-and-alerts) where it states `The drop and keep actions will halt processing if they do or don't match, respectively. For relabel_configs this will cause the target not to be scraped, for metric_relabel_configs this will cause a time series not to be ingested`. Am I reading this incorrectly? All I want is to not scrape certain metrics (in my case, useless metrics)

Comment: @danksim There you have it: "For `relabel_configs` this will cause __*the target*__ not to be scraped, for `metric_relabel_configs` this will cause __*a time series*__ not to be ingested". As you said, you want to avoid certain __*metrics*__ (=time series), while `relabel_configs` could only help you to avoid scraping some __*hosts*__ (=targets). Once again, during `relabel_configs` a connection to the target is not yet established, so you know nothing except SD data. At this point you can't select some metrics out because there are none yet.

Comment: I see. It looks like some `kubernetes_sd_config` meta labels are available at the `relabel_configs` phase but nothing useful to achieve what I want. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I got similar problem with some regular labels (not prefixed by underscores), but replacing `relabel_configs` by `metric_relabel_configs` also worked for me. There is another great explaining article that I want to highlight https://www.robustperception.io/relabel_configs-vs-metric_relabel_configs/