# Drop or rename scrape_config label

Tags: kubernetes, config, prometheus, kube-state-metrics

I'd love to rename or drop a label from a `/metrics` endpoint within my metric. The metric itself is from the `kube-state-metrics` application, so nothing extraordinary. The metric looks like this:

```
kube_pod_container_resource_requests{container="alertmanager", instance="10.10.10.10:8080", funday_monday="blubb", job="some-kube-state-metrics", name="kube-state-metrics", namespace="monitoring", node="some-host-in-azure-1234", pod="alertmanager-main-1", resource="memory", uid="12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012", unit="byte"} 209715200
```

The label I'd love to replace is `instance` because it refers to the host which runs the `kube-state-metrics` application and I don't care about that. I want to have the value of `node` in `instance` and I've been trying so for hours now and can't find a way - I wonder if it's not possible at all!?

The way I'm grabbing the `/metrics` endpoint is through the means of a scrape-config which looks as follows:

```
- job_name: some-kube-state-metrics
      scrape_interval: 30s
      scrape_timeout: 10s
      metrics_path: /metrics
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - api_server: null
        role: pod
      scheme: http
      relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_labelpresent_kubeStateMetrics]
        regex: true
        action: keep
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_name]
        regex: (.*)
        replacement: $1
        target_label: name
        action: replace
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_name]
        separator: ;
        regex: http
        replacement: $1
        action: keep
      - source_labels: [node]
        regex: (.*)
        replacement: blubb
        target_label: funday_monday
        action: replace
      - action: labeldrop
        regex: "unit=(.*)"
      - source_labels: [ __name__ ]
        regex: 'kube\_pod\_container\_resource\_requests'
        action: drop
```

As you can tell, I've been trying to drop labels as well, namely the `unit`-label (just for testing purposes) and I also tried to drop the metrics all together.
The `funday_monday` is an example that changed because I wanted to know if static relabels are possible (it works!) - before it looked like this:

```
- source_labels: [node]
        regex: (.*)
        replacement: $1
        target_label: funday_monday
        action: replace
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing those operations at the wrong time. [relabel_configs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config) happens before metrics are actually gathered, so, at this time, you can only manipulate the labels that you got from [service discovery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#kubernetes_sd_config).

That `node` label comes from the exporter. Therefore, you need to do this relabeling action under [metric_relabel_configs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#metric_relabel_configs):

```yaml
metric_relabel_configs:
- source_labels: [node]
  target_label: instance
```

Same goes for dropping metrics. If you wish a bit more info, I answered a similar question here: [prometheus relabel_config drop action not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70355080/prometheus-relabel-config-drop-action-not-working/70359287#70359287)