# Replace "exported_instance" label value from Prometheus

Tags: configuration, yaml, prometheus, grafana

this label (exported_instance) is always added in every metric automatically.

```
myMetric{exported_instance="HP-probook", instance="ss:9966", job="ss"}
```

How can I replace during scrape time from prometheus.yml?
Is it possibile? Or I need to add new one?

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__address__]
   regex: 'HP-probook'
    target_label: new_label
    replacement: 'HP-probook-2'
```

I understand that it is added automatically and for this reason it is not clear to me if I can replace it without adding another one.

Thanks Alen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`job` and `instance` labels are somewhat special with Prometheus. `instance` comes from the `__address__` label and represents a host and port from which the metric came.

You get metrics with `exported_` prefix if the collected data already have one of the predefined labels. In other words, `exported_instance` is the `instance` label in your exporter.

The best way around this is to **avoid using any of the special labels** in the exporter. If for some reason it is mandatory to use one of these labels, you can perform relabeling at the `metric_relabel_configs`:

```yaml
metric_relabel_configs:
# copy exported_instance value to label foo
- source_labels: [exported_instance]
  target_label: foo
# remove exported_instance label
- action: labeldrop
  regex: ^exported_instance$
```

Remember that you cannot use `relabel_configs` to deal with labels that come from an exporter, you need `metric_relabel_configs` for this. Here is another my answer with the explanation: [prometheus relabel_config drop action not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70355080/prometheus-relabel-config-drop-action-not-working/70359287#70359287)